# Regex that won't allow for matches with 2 or more dots?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Right now I have a list of strings, and some of these strings have consecutive dots in them. I want to match everything except those strings with consecutive dots. For example:

```
fo.o.ba.r = legal --> fo..obar != legal
```

This is the regex I've tried using, but it doesn't seem to work how I thought it would.

```
(?!\.{2,})
```

Can anyone here put me on the right path? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the start of the string to the end of the string, repeat any character inside a group while using negative lookahead for two dots:

```
^(?:(?!\.{2}).)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/M5nhk7/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert from the start of the string that what is on the right does not contain 2 dots:

`^(?!.*\.{2}).+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZuMLyx/1)

That will match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*` Match any character 0+ times
  - `\.{2}` Match 2 times a dot
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.+` Match any character 1+ times
- `$` Assert the end of the string